# if multiple redirection operators in one command line, How these works ? (bash)

Tags: bash, unix

if redirection operator multiple in one command. (bash)

1. same redirection operator.
   Ex.
   `arg_1 > arg_2 > arg_3 > arg_4`
2. different redirection operator.
   Ex.
   `arg_1 < arg_2 > arg_3 < arg_4 < arg_5 > arg_6`

i know if one redirection operator in command how working.

but
if multiple redirection operators in one command line, How these works ?

Comment: Try it and see? All the `< arg_x` files need to exist, but input will be redirected from the final one. All the `> arg_x` files will be created and truncated, but output will be redirected to the final one.

Comment: Some shells treat conflicting redirects as an error, but I believe `bash` just overrides earlier conflicting redirects, so the last one takes effect.

Comment: I tested some cases. ```command < 3.c > 1.c < 4.c > 5.c < 6.c``` If an error ("< 4.c : 4.c file is not exist" or "command not found") occurs in the middle of a command,  i'm not sure the remaining commands end without executing them

Comment: @TomKarzes what is conflicting redirects?

Comment: @gigi Conflicting redirects is the subject of your post.  If you have more than one `>` or more than one `<`, they conflict with each other.  In some shells, it's an error.  In `bash`, it disregards all but the last.  If you have `foo > f1 > f2 > f3`, the redirects of standard output to `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` all conflict with each other.  This is something you normally want to avoid.  In `bash`, it's equivalent to `foo > f3`.  The redirect to `f1` is overridden by the redirect to `f2`, which in turn is overridden by the redirect to `f3`.

Comment: @TomKarzes i didn't know about conflict thank you! and conflicting redirections case include different redirections case ( Ex ```foo > f1 < f2 < f3 > f4```)?

Comment: @gigi The order doesn't matter for those.  In that example, `f1` and `f4` conflict (they both attempt to redirect standard output), and `f2` and `f3` conflict (they both attempt to redirect standard input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirections are evaluated from left to right. Think of `>foo` as kind of *stdout=foo*. Hence the redirection in

```
prog >foo >bar
```

corresponds to setting

```
stdout=foo
stdout=bar
```

, which means that overall, stdout ends up redirected to *bar* (like when setting a variable first to one value and then to some different value), but because setting stdout to a file **also** has the effect of creating this file, both *foo* and *bar* will exist in the end, even though nothing will be written into *foo*.

Similarily,

```
prog >foo 2>&1 >bar
```

would do a

```
stdout=foo
stderr=stdout
stdout=bar
```

and you would have stdout going to *bar*  and stderr going to *foo*. Of course you would in practice simply write `prog 2>foo >bar`, to achieve this effect.